# Parsing URL with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out why my page is not working as expect (even though it was working previously).

Here is the page:
http://www.taconic.com/resources/webinars/archive/hla-transgenic-mice-development-validation-and-applications.html

The functionality on this page was set as such when you submit the form, the contact goes away and the video displays - using a URL parameter.

Here is my JS (and style code for this page):

```
    <style>
    .dynamic-content {
        display:none;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Parse the URL parameter
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        // Give the parameter a variable name
        var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('webinar');

         $(document).ready(function() {

            // Check if the URL parameter is hla
            if (dynamicContent == 'yes') {
                $('#yes').show();
            } 
            // Check if the URL parmeter is empty or not defined, display   default content
        else {
            $('#default-content').show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

On Submit the form redirects the user to http://www.taconic.com/resources/webinars/archive/hla-transgenic-mice-development-validation-and-applications.html?webinar=hla.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Open up the developer console. Errors galore

Comment: You haven't clearly defined a problem and explained difference between what it should do and what it is doing now. Refer to [ask]

Comment: how is this not clear: The functionality on this page was set as such when you submit the form, all the content goes away and the video displays - using a URL parameter?

Comment: @epascarello, four errors - none of which have to with the functionality that I'm specifically trying to fix.

Comment: So how does "hla"==="yes"

Comment: @epascarello, yes with the URL parameter "webinar=hla"

Comment: How does `"yes"` equal `"hla"`? Hint hint.... that is your problem.

Comment: I'm officially dumb - thank you.

Comment: Or you need some fresh air! I debugged code for 20 minutes yesterday to find out I was in the wrong development environment. :)

Comment: Been there, done that - I've screamed at our live environment for an hour because the changes I was making in test were not showing up. :) cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha - thanks all for the quick fix.

```
   <style>
    .dynamic-content {
        display:none;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Parse the URL parameter
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        // Give the parameter a variable name
        var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('webinar');

         $(document).ready(function() {

            // Check if the URL parameter is hla
            if (dynamicContent == 'hla') {
                $('#hla').show();
            } 
            // Check if the URL parmeter is empty or not defined, display default content
            else {
                $('#default-content').show();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You url parameter is "hla" and your if statement says if the url parameter equals "yes" than show the movie.

So "yes" and "hal" will not match ever.

Change your url to be http://www.taconic.com/resources/webinars/archive/hla-transgenic-mice-development-validation-and-applications.html?webinar=yes and the player shows up.